# Is this a valid React HoC use case?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, design-patterns, high-order-component

I'm introducing myself to React's HoC pattern.

I have a video player component that sometimes needs to have a `select` to change a parameter in the video src url.

To simplify things, this a reduced version of my HoC:

```js
function withTimeControl(PlayerComponent) {
  return class extends Component {
    state = {
      src: ''
    }

    updatePlayerDelay = (event) => {
      this.setState({
        src: event.target.value
      })
    }

    render() {
      return(
        <div>
          <PlayerComponent 
            title={this.props.title}
            src={this.state.src}
          />

          <PlayerTimeComtrol
            label={this.props.label}
            onChangeHandler={this.updatePlayerDelay}
          />
        </div>
      );
    }
  };
}
```

And to use it, I would do:

```js
const PlayerWithTimeControl = withTimeControl(Player)

// ...

<PlayerWithTimeControl title='Player title' label='Time control label' />
```

Where `PlayerComponent` is the component being wrapped. The HoC basically ads a component, `PlayerTimeComtrol` to change the src of the video player.

Is this valid use case? Are there other more accurate solutions to this? Maybe just use a component wrapper and not a HoC?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is technically an approach that can be used. But HOCs typically deal with data flow addition/interception, as opposed to UI. IMO, they should be used sparingly. This really feels like overengineering, when you can just have `PlayerTimeComtrol` accept a `children` prop and wrap it around `PlayerComponent`

```js
<PlayerTimeComtrol
  label={this.props.label}
  onChangeHandler={this.updatePlayerDelay}
>
  // with whatever component you want here
</PlayerTimeControl>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that's exactly what HoCs are for: adding functionalities to existing components.

Comment: You can make your entire app a stack of hooks, but that doesn't mean it's a good idea.

Comment: I understand what they are for. My question was more orientend to a "good practice" point of view.